# What is the best user experience for user to perform an action using email?

Tags: users, user-registration

If I want a user to confirm his participation on an event that my website represents, what is the best way to offer him the possibility to do this? If I send an information email to him, with a link to confirm his attendance to the event, he has to be logged in in order for me to get his information and change his status in the database. Other way is to use nonce I think, is this the correct way to do, or am I missing something on the way here? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: in the link in the e-mail, you can add an argument wich identify the user and then save his participation without the need of being connected

Comment: argument nonce?